# Find column first, then value in column

Tags: excel

I am having trouble figuring out how to write a function to return a value from a column. Let's say I have a big master list of excluded numbers with columns 1,2,3,4,5,6. In each column is a bunch of values, anywhere from 1-500, and each column can have repeat values or be missing values.

I'll regularly be getting large lists of values and their corresponding columns that I will need to verify are in or not in the master list.

If I get two columns of data, one of values and one of their corresponding columns to cross check in the master list, is there a function or group of functions that will do this?

Sort of like a VLOOKUP, but instead of starting at the left most column, it looks at the column that my list tells it to and then looks for the value my list has. I'm having trouble figuring it out with an INDEX/MATCH because the values can show up on different rows in each column since some columns have omitted numbers.

Comment: Are you going to use VBA or just Excel worksheet functions?

Comment: `=COUNTIF(INDEX(A:F,0,X),Y)` where `X` is the column number and `Y` is the number you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of an answer, a Comment from [@tigeravatar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2665425/tigeravatar):

> `=COUNTIF(INDEX(A:F,0,X),Y)` where X is the column number and Y is the number you're looking for.